# $\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{b_{n}}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, riemann-integration

> Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ ne a sequence of continuous functions on
>   $[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that converges uniformly to
>   $f:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Let $(b_n)_{n\in\mathbb{R}}$ be an
>   increasing sequence of real numbers in $(0,1)$ that converges to 1.
>   Prove that : $$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{b_{n}}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$

As far as I know if we have a sequence of functions converging uniformly to $f$ **AND** if they are uniformly bounded we can have the following: $$\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}{\lim}\int_{0}^{1}f_n(x)dx=\int_0^1f(x)dx$$.
But here it is not so. Even the uniform boundedness is also not mentioned.

Comment: Uniform convergence is sufficient for the interchange of limit with the integral.

Comment: Thank you for correcting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint:

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we have for all sufficiently large $n$
$$\left|\int_0^{b_n} f_n - \int_0^1 f \right| \leqslant \int_0^{b_n}|f_n - f| + \int_{b_n}^1 |f| \leqslant \epsilon b_n + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| (1 - b_n)$$

Comment: Thanks. It works. But I need a small clarification: 
is it always true that $|\int f dx|\leq\int|f|dx$? If so can you please point out a website or a book which state this result? 

Thanks again!

Comment: So $-|f(x)| \leqslant f(x) \leqslant |f(x)|$. One side gives us $\int_0^1f \leqslant \int_0^1|f|$. The other side gives us $-\int_0^1|f| \leqslant \int_0^1 f$. Thus $|\int_0^1 f| \leqslant \int_0^1 |f|$.

Comment: Ah! So it is the proof. Thank you!

Comment: @DD90: You are welcome.